# Returning to 'MouseEnter' Color After 'MouseDown' is Called?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a test C# WinForm Application and I have a closing button. When you hover over the button, the BackColor changes to a lighter color. When you stop hovering over it, the button changes back to the background color. Upon clicking the button, it changes to white, and when letting go, changes back to the background color. My question is, if someone hovers over and it changes to the hover color, then someone clicks and changes the color again, if they drag their mouse off of the button, can I make it change back to the hover color?

***Code:***

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bunifuImageButton1.MouseEnter += bunifuImageButton1_MouseHover;
        bunifuImageButton1.MouseLeave += bunifuImageButton1_MouseLeave;
        bunifuImageButton1.MouseDown += bunifuImageButton1_MouseDown;
        bunifuImageButton1.MouseUp += bunifuImageButton1_MouseUp;
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could track if the mouse is down, and if the mouse is down and it leaves the button, change the color to the hover color.

There is a catch though, because `MouseLeave` doesn't fire if the mouse is down, so you need to check the mouse position on the `MouseMove` event, like this:

```
private bool isMouseDown;

private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
}

private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    isMouseDown = true;
}

private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
    isMouseDown = false;
}

private void bunifuImageButton1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // If the mouse is down and the mouse is not over the button
    if (isMouseDown && !bunifuImageButton1.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        bunifuImageButton1.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a flat styled button setting the flatappearence colors, and see how it does the job automatically.

Comment: I tried using a flat button and set it to flat. Everything works except when I hold click on the button and drag off, the color changes but instead of it changing to the hover color, it changes to a grayer shade of white.